# Why do Primitive Data Types have a Fixed Size?

Tags: long-integer

In some of the programming languages, typically *C*, *C++* and *Java*, the integer data types are `int`, `short` and `long`.
The `int` data type is usually 32-bit. The `short` data type is usually smaller than the `int` data type, and the `long` data type is usually larger than the `int` data type.

The first *bit* of an integer data type is the *bit* sign.
A negative number starts with '1' and a non-negative number starts with '0'.

Therefore, a *32-bit data type normally* stores numbers in the range `-(2^31)` to `(2^31 - 1)`.

Why can't we have a data type of unlimited size, so that we can store an unlimited range of numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As low-level programming languages, the designs of C and C++ closely follow what common hardware is capable of. The primitive building blocks (fundamental types) correspond to entities that common CPUs natively support. CPUs typically can handle bytes and words very efficiently; C called these `char` and `int`. (More precisely, C defined `int` in such a way that a compiler could use the target CPU's word size for it.) There has also been CPU support for double-sized words, which historically corresponded to the `long` data type in C, later to the `long long` types of C and C++. Half-words corresponded to `short`. The basic integer types correspond to things a CPU can handle well, with enough flexibility to accommodate different architectures. (For example, if a CPU did not support half-words, `short` could be the same size as `int`.)

If there was hardware support for integers of unbounded size (limited only by available memory), then there could be an argument for adding that as a fundamental type in C (and C++). Until that happens, support of big integers (see [bigint](/questions/tagged/bigint)) in C and C++ has been relegated to libraries.

Some of the newer, higher-level languages do have built-in support for arbitrary-precision arithmetic.

Answer (score 3):

Simple answer: Performance

For all three of C, C++ and Java there exists libraries for big integers. But using these libraries typically have much worse performance than regular data types. Both in terms of cpu time and memory usage.

> The first bit of an integer data type is the bit sign. A negative number starts with '1' and a non-negative number starts with '0'.

Not necessarily. One complement numbers does not work that way for example. And a few other ways of representing negative numbers does not too. And even if two complement indeed starts with 1 for negative numbers, it's not really a sign bit.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations